# Play Framework 2.1-RC2: NoSuchFieldError's created by reverse routing in templates

Tags: java, routes, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am working on a Java Play 2.1-RC2 application with MongoDB as the data store. I'm using the Jongo module for working with MongoDB.
All was going well until I got these kind of errors:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Home

These errors originate from my templates and are caused by using reverse routing. In this particular case I'm trying to reach my Home controller.

The reverse route looks like this: 
@routes.Home.edit(document.url)

and the route itself like this:
GET     /homepage/:url/edit                controllers.Home.edit(url)

This worked before, but has started giving these errors since I started working on the MongoDB implementation. I can't figure out what would be the connection between the two. I don't think I'm interfering with the routing in any way.
This project started of as a 2.0.4 project. Migration to 2.1-RC1 went fine and 2.1-RC2 seemed to work as well, until now. I have created my own Model convenience class for working with Mongo models. Could there be anything in there that's causing this behavior?

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "_class")
public class Model {

  @JsonProperty("_id")
  public ObjectId id;

  public MongoCollection models() {
    String collectionName = this.getClass().getName() + "s";
    return PlayJongo.getCollection(collectionName);
  }

  public void save() {
    models().save(this);
  }

  public void update() {
    this.remove();
    this.save();
  }

  public void remove() {
    models().remove(this.id);
  }

  public static class Finder<T> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    public Finder(Class<T> type) {
      this.type = type;
    }

    public MongoCollection models() {
      String collectionName = type.getName() + "s";
      return PlayJongo.getCollection(collectionName);
    }

    public List<T> all() {

      List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
      Iterator<T> it = models().find().as(type).iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        list.add(it.next());
      }
      return list;
    }

    public T byId(ObjectId id) {
      return models().findOne(id).as(type);
    }

    public T byUrl(String url) {
      return models().findOne("{url: #}", url).as(type);
    }

    public List<T> byQuery(String query) {
      List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
      Iterator<T> it = models().find(query).as(type).iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        list.add(it.next());
      }
      return list;
    }
  }
```

My plugins.sbt:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1-RC2")
```

My build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.12.2-RC2
```

My Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "Test"
  val appVersion = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    "uk.co.panaxiom" %% "play-jongo" % "0.3"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    lessEntryPoints <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(base => (
      (base / "assets" / "css" / "bootstrap.less") +++
        (base / "assets" / "css" / "responsive.less")
      )
    )
  )
}
```

The only application.conf lines that could be relevant:

```
playjongo.uri="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test"
playjongo.gridfs.enabled=false

ehcacheplugin=enabled
```

And the stacktrace:

```
! @6d48738mo - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Home]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1-RC2]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1-RC2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:114) [play_2.10.jar:2.1-RC2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:110) [play_2.10.jar:2.1-RC2]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1-RC2]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1-RC2]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Home
    at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:377) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1-RC2]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Home
    at views.html.documents.homepage$.apply(homepage.template.scala:45) ~[na:na]
    at views.html.documents.homepage$.render(homepage.template.scala:51) ~[na:na]
    at views.html.documents.homepage.render(homepage.template.scala) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Home.read(Home.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$17$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(routes_routing.scala:251) ~[na:na]
```

If anyone could tell me where these errors could be coming from or point me in the right direction I would be very grateful! If you need more information please let me know!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I've noticed that application works properly when I use `play start` command.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed when using the start command my application runs again! It's a really strange issue, but at least I can continue developing! Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Hi @DennisV. and @biesior any progress on this? Could you get it working with `play run`? I'm having the exact same issue and its very frustrating!

Comment: Hey @monsieurBelbo, yes 'play start' was working but it had a huge impact on my productivity. I ended up ditching the Jongo plugin and in stead went with the Jackson mapper plugin. I was able to start using it with a minimal amount of code rewriting. 

https://github.com/vznet/play-mongo-jackson-mapper

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that was a solution, but I was trying to leave it to a last resort. I'll go that way then. Thanks, @DennisV. !

Comment: FYI, I've created a bug in the Play issue tracker for this, since it's still happening in version 2.1.1. https://github.com/playframework/Play20/issues/1123 Note that I've narrowed it down to the module being used including some assets in its routes file.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had the exact same error with Play 2.1.0 and after two nights spent on it seems like I've finally found where the problem is !

The module that I was using had a controller named controllers.Application with its route filled in the conf/routes file of the module and I have the exact same controller in my project (also with the route). It seems that it was the source of the problem for me.

So look in your modules (or sub-projects?) for conflicting controllers or routes and it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should append parameter type in route. So it should be:

```
 GET /homepage/:url/edit controllers.Home.edit(url: String)
```

There are several example in Play documentation which not do this. But I think declare explisit type is a best practice.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but as I expected it did not change anything. String parameters do not need to be explicitly declared. Thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hongsw/play2-JongoModel

I made a sample project for JongoModel

(Play! Framework 2.1)